# Extract URI parts without using libraries

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source

Given a URI like:

```
postgres://username:password@hostname:PORT/dbname
```

Extract it all into an array data-structure, like so:

```
['postgres', 'username', 'password', 'hostname', 'PORT', 'dbname']
```

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax

#### Rules

- No use of external libraries or web-services

#### Scoring

- Your score will be the number of bytes in your code (whitespace not included) multiplied by your bonus. Initial bonus is 1.0.
- Concision is king (codegolf!)
- Use of regular expressions will increase your bonus by 0.50
- Use of internal libraries (that need explicit importing) will increase your bonus by 0.50
- Extra -0.8 bonus for getting query string also

Comment: "No use of internal/external libraries which need importing" - why? This basically prevents Java from participating. Also, we need a better spec. Which parts need to be extracted? How about the query string of HTTP URIs?

Comment: What is defined by internal library here ?

Comment: Clarified my question

Comment: x2 penalty to Java is brutal. As if `import java.util.*` wasn't penalty enough.

Comment: Okay @Optimizer, updated

Comment: Please use [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) next time...

Comment: One example does not make a spec. You should *at the very least* specify how the output should vary with the following variations to the input: no scheme name; no username and password; no port; no path; multi-segment path; containing query string; containing fragment; containing both; pure relative URI (i.e. no scheme or authority). Test cases for protocols with different numbers of slashes (e.g. `file:///` and `urn:`) should also be included.

Comment: Whitespace not included...are you banning Whitespace or giving Whitespace a 0 byte count?

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 15 bytes * 0.8 = 12

```
l":@?#"'/er'/%p
```

Reads the uri via STDIN. Updated to parse query string and fragments too.

**Code explanation**:

```
l                    "Read a line from STDIN";
 ":@?#"              "Put this string on stack";
       '/er          "Replace all occurrences of characters in above string by /";
           '/%       "Split on runs of /";
              p      "Print the array";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%22%3A%40%3F%23%22%27%2Fer%27%2F%25p&input=postgres%3A%2F%2Fusername%3Apassword%40hostname%3APORT%2Fdbname%3Fkey1%3Dvalue1%26key2%3Dvalue2%26key3%3Dvalue3%23anchorORfragment)

Comment: Maybe you can go for the query string bonus

Answer (score 0):

### APL, 24

```
 {⍵⊂⍨⍵∊⎕AV[∊65 17+¨⊂⍳26]}
```

Example:

```
 ]display {⍵⊂⍨⍵∊⎕AV[∊65 17+¨⊂⍳26]}'postgres://username:password@hostname:PORT/dbname'
┌→────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌→───────┐ ┌→───────┐ ┌→───────┐ ┌→───────┐ ┌→───┐ ┌→─────┐ │
│ │postgres│ │username│ │password│ │hostname│ │PORT│ │dbname│ │
│ └────────┘ └────────┘ └────────┘ └────────┘ └────┘ └──────┘ │
└∊────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Note: ⎕ML variable must be set to 3 in Dyalog APL

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 43

```ruby
%w[:// : @ /].map{|t|u.gsub! t,' '}
u.split
```

Since the OP doesn't specify how to take input and produce output, I'm assuming the URI is located in `u` as a `String`. There is no output; `u.split` returns an Array in the correct format (`["postgres", "username", "password", "hostname", "PORT", "dbname"]`).

The code itself is simple. Replace `"://"`, `":"`, `"@"` and `"/`" with a space, then split on whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

### Python (characters: 207, score: 240)

```python
reduce(list.__add__,reduce(list.__add__,map(lambda e: map(lambda i: i.split('/'),e),map(lambda j: j.split(':'),(lambda e:e[e.find('/')+2:].split('@'))('postgres://username:password@hostname:PORT/dbname')))))
```

#### Expanded out

```python
reduce(list.__add__,
       reduce(list.__add__,
              map(lambda e: map(lambda i: i.split('/'), e),
                  map(lambda elem: elem.split(':'),
                      (lambda e: e[e.find('//') + 2:].split('@'))(
                          'postgres://username:password@hostname:PORT/dbname'
                      )
                  )
              )
       )
)
```

Note: in real-cases use `from operator import add`

Comment: It looks like you've written some Haskell in Python!

Comment: By the way, Python has `int.__add__`. Also, it looks like your code is a snippet rather than a program or function, as it expect the variable `url` to be pre-initialized with the input. This is not allowed by default for code golf, so if you intend it to be allowed, you should say so in the spec.

Comment: "It looks like you've written some Haskell in Python!" :P - Yeah, good find; using `list.__add__` now.

Comment: This doesn't take input or do output.

Comment: I never said it had to? - Replace my constant with a variable or stdin call if you like, and throw a print statement in. Not needed though.